# Using Final For If Conditional

Tags: java

I know how to use final to set an int, like this:

```
final int junk = whatever ? 1 : 2;
```

But, how to do this in more complicated if statements?

Comment: @Pix what exactly do you mean by more complicated? An example may be?

Comment: What did you try that failed?

Comment: He probably means `whatever` is a possibly expensive expression that shouldn't be evaluated twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### How to use Java "final" To Set a Value in an if() Conditional

**Example**:

```
final int junk;
if(whatever) {
    junk = 1;
} else {
    junk = 2;
}
```

You can nest final value setting to any depth, and Java will flag an error if you make any duplicates or skip any paths.

**Example**:

```
final int junk;
if(whatever) {
    junk = 1;
} else {
    if(however) {
        junk = 2;
    } else {
        junk = 3;
    }
}
```

I use `final` for local variable closure whenever possible to insure that I don't accidentally reuse variables unexpectedly.

Comment: And that's called blank final I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `?` operator for nested *if-statements* like this:

```
final int junk = whatever ? 1 : whatever2 ? 3 : 4; .... and so on
```

(If thats what you mean by saying *"complicated"*)

Although, when you have a *"complicated*" condition, it's more readable to use `if-else` rather than the `?` operator.